# Algorithm to find 2 consecutive numbers

Tags: arrays, list, sorting, numbers

Consider a list of unsorted numbers, think about an algorithm to test all the items in the list to check whether there are any two consecutive numbers (even if they are not adjacent) or not.

- For example 1: List A = [10,7,23,18,45,24]-> output: true

  - the output is True becasue 23 and 24 are consecutive numbers (even not adjacent)
- For example 2: List B = [24,15,18,18,42,22]-> output: false

  - the output of example 2 is False because there isn't any consecutive numbers.

Now, answer the following questions:

1. Write an algorithm to solve the above problem?

Comment: First, add the text here, not an image. Second, try something and post it here if it doesn't work, then we could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implement this with Go language. [find full code here and run](https://play.golang.org/p/yD-g3tEHgrK)

```
func isConsecutiveAvailable(arr []int) bool{
    // sort the array in increasing order
    sort.Ints(arr)
    
    // loop the array and find if there is a consecutive
    for i:=0; i < len(arr) -1; i++ {
        if arr[i] + 1 == arr[i+1]{
            return true
        }
    }
    
    // return false if loop cant find any consecutive
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the list from lowest to highest, then check in sets of 2 to check for consecutive numbers.